# How do I call methods of all elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas

i have a class named obj which has several methods in it and a method called callAllFunctions() which just calls each and every method in it like this ->

```js
callAllFunctions(){
  method1()
  Method2()
}
```

I made it so that everytime I touch the screen a new obj is spawned at the x and y postion of the mouse/finger and store it in an array ( this will make sense in the code)
But here's the problem

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

canvas.height = window.innerHeight
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.style = "background-color:#556479;"

//resize the window

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
})

let RandomNum = (max, min) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function randomArray(arr) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
}

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2))
  //let root = Math.round(Math.pow(distance , 2))
  return distance
}

function clamp(value, min, max) {
  return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max)
}
class obj {
  constructor(x, y, c) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.ysp = 1
    this.xsp = 2
    this.c = c

  }
  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.c
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 10, Math.PI * 2, 0)
    ctx.fill()

  }
  update() {
    this.ysp += 0.5

    if (this.ysp < 0) {
      this.ysp += 0.5
    }

    this.x += this.xsp
    this.y += this.ysp
  }
  limit() {
    this.x = clamp(this.x, 0, canvas.width)
    this.y = clamp(this.y, 0, canvas.height)
  }
  bounce() {
    if (this.y + this.ysp > canvas.height || this.y + this.ysp < 0) {
      this.xsp -= 0.05
      if (this.xsp < 0.6) {
        this.xsp = 0
      }
      this.ysp *= -1
    } else if (this.x + this.xsp > canvas.width || this.x + this.xsp < 0) {
      this.xsp -= 0.05
      if (this.xsp < 0.6) {
        this.xsp = 0
      }
      this.xsp *= -1
    }
  }
  callAllFunctions() {
    this.bounce()
    this.update()
    this.draw()
    this.limit()
  }
}

let mouse = { "x": 20, "y": 20 }
let canvasBounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  mouse.x = e.x - canvasBounds.x;
  mouse.y = e.y - canvasBounds.y;
});
let a = new obj(100,100,"#fff")
let balls = [a]


canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  balls.push(new obj(mouse.x, mouse.y, "#fff"))
  console.log(balls)
})

let clear = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
}
setInterval(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
   balls[i].callAllFunctions()
  }
  clear()
}, 17)
```

I tried to do `balls[i].callAllFunctions` but it gives the error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'callAllFunctions')
at http://localhost:7700/main.js:106:13
```

Why is it so and what can be it's remedy?

Html

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>HTML</title>
  
  <!-- HTML -->
  

  <!-- Custom Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Css

```css
body {
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
canvas{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Update on the problem
I used for each instead of a for loop so it removed any erros and I also console logged it to see it's working and it's fine the only problem being i just can't see any objects on the screen , I'm not sure why it's not rendering..
Here's the updated code

```js
balls.forEach((e) => {
    e.callAllFunctions()
    console.log(e)
  })
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make a [mcve] using the snippet `[<>]` function in the edit toolbar.

Comment: btw, you do not use `e`, but `mouse`.

Comment: @NinaScholz this is the event listener for the canvas i have a seperate one in which i store the mouse's x and y position in a mouse object so it's mouse.x and mouse.y

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images. Also, please include the full error stack, not just the error message. - ideally put your whole code into a _snippet_ (using the `<>` button) so it's runnable inside the question itself.

Comment: @CherryDT I'm sorry , I'm not very experienced with stack overflow but , to make it runnable do I add the html and css code too? Because I don't think this will run

Comment: Yes, you set HTML and CSS too. (I suggested it because I saw you just had an HTML file, a JS file and a CSS file, so I figured it'd run in a snippet too)

Comment: Uh it says touch devices not supported :/ , but i added the html , css and full js code too

Answer (score 2):

The question is not clear, but I guess you might have an error in the condition of the `for` loop (using `>=` instead of <):

```
  for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {}
```

Comment: My bad lemme just fix that in the question